# ANR ERROR : input dispatching time out When mobile screen turned on

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I am getting this ANR error when  phone screen goes off and i turned it on again app is doing write but when i turn screen off , on app got freezed and shows anr dialog

```
E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.example.iotsmarthouses (com.example.iotsmarthouses/.Activities.MainActivity)
    PID: 3448
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 3.  Wait queue head age: 5803.8ms.)
    Load: 0.48 / 0.28 / 0.22
    CPU usage from 74907ms to 0ms ago (2020-05-02 10:37:09.155 to 2020-05-02 10:38:24.062):
      3.7% 519/system_server: 2.1% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 16227 minor
      3.3% 404/surfaceflinger: 1.6% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 112 minor
      2.3% 334/local_opengl: 0% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 501 minor
      2.2% 391/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 0.2% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 23 minor
      1% 165/adbd: 0.4% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 61096 minor
      0.8% 675/com.android.systemui: 0.5% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 568 minor
      0.6% 398/audioserver: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 4 minor
      0.6% 384/android.hardware.audio@2.0-service: 0% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 13 minor
      0.6% 159/redis: 0.4% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.5% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
      0.4% 389/android.hardware.gnss@1.0-service: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.4% 1400/com.android.launcher3: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 556 minor
      0.3% 396/android.hardware.sensors@1.0-service: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 3370/com.example.myapplication: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 466 minor
      0.2% 338/batteryd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 392/android.hardware.health@2.0-service.genymotion: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 133/logd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 10 minor
      0.1% 2845/kworker/u8:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 20/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0% 1768/com.android.packageinstaller: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 487 minor
      0% 667/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 103 minor
      0% 131/jbd2/sdb3-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 390/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor
      0% 839/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 41 minor
      0% 6/kworker/u8:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 12/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 339/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
      0% 373/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 402/network_profile: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 406/vinput: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 444/wificond: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 16/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 134/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 175/mdnsd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 257/hostapd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 340/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 132 minor
      0% 393/android.hardware.light@2.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 394/android.hardware.memtrack@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 395/android.hardware.power@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 397/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 442/statsd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 448/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 683/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 2734/kworker/3:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 3161/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 3445/kworker/u8:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 3448/com.example.iotsmarthouses: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 3504/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
    5.9% TOTAL: 3.5% user + 1.9% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.4% softirq
    CPU usage from 10ms to 267ms later (2020-05-02 10:38:24.072 to 2020-05-02 10:38:24.329):
      30% 519/system_server: 25% user + 4.3% kernel / faults: 377 minor
        17% 529/HeapTaskDaemon: 17% user + 0% kernel
        12% 546/ActivityManager: 12% user + 0% kernel
        4.3% 526/ReferenceQueueD: 0% user + 4.3% kernel
      4.7% 3448/com.example.iotsmarthouses: 4.7% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
       +0% 3509/Binder:3448_4: 0% user + 0% kernel
    9.9% TOTAL: 7.9% user + 1.9% kernel
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2169: eglSurfaceAttrib(1354): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
```

i know this anr will happen in heavy ui thread proccess but i dont know why when the mobile screen turned on this had happen

Comment: are you doing the writing in a different thread than UI? post the code that is causing this error

Comment: i khow what you said if this has been happend anr should showed at first not after screen turned on and i care of this things

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean